# Applying CSS styles to RDL file

Tags: css, reporting-services, rdl

Is there any way to apply CSS styles to an SSRS rdl file ?

Note: it's not necessary to BIDS, my main goal is to edit the rdl file regardless of the used tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From what I read, an RDL file is written in XML so yes, you can use XSLT to turn it into HTML, to which you can apply CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well sort of.  You can do what Mario suggested but you can't really do that to the RDL as is.  You need to CALL IT from a service to HTML and then apply a CSS to that.  The RDL File contains definitions but not the report data.  So if you changed it for markup you would still have to connect to a database and read the RDL language.  As far as I know RDL is a propertiary SSRS langauge that needs a converter to tell it how to display.  This is generally the service at http:// (servername)/ReportServer which has the information built in that can translate it.  You could not alter this file directly without A LOT of work to transform it as it would then need to know a connection string, how the data was presented.

To do what you want I would think you could do this:

1. Deploy a report
2. Call a form to be populated in HTML like:

   ```
   <form id="ssrsform" action="http://(servername)/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx(Path)&rs:Command=Render" method="post" target="_self" >
   .....(options and settings)....
   </form>
   ```
3. Apply a CSS form to the HTML file directly that is calling the webserivce.

IMHO changing a proprietary language file like RDL before it transmits to HTML would be hard as you need to account for the data you get as well as just the connection string.